# pass arguments like onChange and onClick to a react component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, onchange

I'm trying to create a page with react, for that I'm using typescript.

In the project there is a component that is an input and in it I want there to be an `onChange` function, but when I put it in the component, it has a red dash, indicating that there is an error, how could I pass the `onChange` correctly? I know how to do it using javascript, but not with typescript.

I made the code as follows:

```
import { StyledInput } from "./Input.styles";

export const Input = ( { onChange } ) => {
    return(
        <StyledInput onChange={onChange}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the prop type, e.g.

```
export const Input = ( { onChange }:{ onChange:(x:string)=>void } ) => {
```

Or more precisely

```js
type Props ={ onChange:React.ComponentProps<typeof<StyledInput>>['onChange'] }
export const Input = ( { onChange }:Props ) => {
```

This approach ensures that if you're 3rd party package type signature changes you still have the same precise type defined in your props